# Python defaultdict deep nested data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, defaultdict

I have a list of excel datasets with certain information as below:

```
Category    Subcategory    Name
Main Dish   Noodle         Tomato Noodle
Main Dish   Stir Fry       Chicken Rice
Main Dish   Soup           Beef Goulash
Drink       Wine           Bordeaux
Drink       Softdrink      Cola
```

Suppose the above dataset is only one of the datasets, my desired data structure using nested dict and list is:

```
data = {0:{'data':0, 'Category':[
                                 {'name':'Main Dish', 'Subcategory':[
                                                       {'name':'Noodle', 'key':0, 'data':['key':1, 'title':'Tomato Noodle']},
                                                       {'name':'Stir Fry', 'key':1, 'data':['key':2, 'title':'Chicken Rice']},
                                                       {'name':'Soup', 'key':2, 'data':['key':3, 'title':'Beef Goulash']}]},
                                  {'name':'Drink', 'Subcategory':[
                                                       {'name':'Wine', 'key':0, 'data':['key':1, 'title':'Bordeaux']},
                                                       {'name':'Softdrink', 'key':1, 'data':['key':2, 'title':'cola'}]}]},
        1:{'data':1, 'Category':.........#Same structure as dataset 0}}
```

So basically, the whole category is a defaultdict(list), each different categories form a dict within the whole category list. So do the different subcategories, but subcategories follow category.

I tried to use the defaultdict to do it, here are my codes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(dict)
cateList = ["Main Dish", "Drink"]
n = 3 # n means the number of datasets
for i in range(n):
    data[i]['data'] = i
    data[i]['category'] = defaultdict(list) 
    for j in range(len(cateList)):
        data[i]['category'][j]['name'] = cateList[j]
        data[i]['category'][j]['subcategory'] = defaultdict(list)
data
```

But I receive the following errors:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-298f7ff30c6a> in <module>()
      5     data[i]['category'] = defaultdict(list)
      6     for j in range(len(cateList)):
----> 7         c
      8         data[i]['category'][j]['subcategory'] = defaultdict(list)
      9 data

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is executed in Jupyter Notebook, and it seems that it doesn't allow me to indicate the nested defaultdict in this way: data[i]['category'][j]['name'] = cateList[j]. So I am not quite sure how construct the above data structure...is there a better way?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `data[i]['category']` is a dictionary (a `defaultdict(list)` instance), and `data[i]['category'][j]` is a list. You can't use a string (`'subcategory')` to index lists.

Comment: Also, your lists would be empty, assigning to a list index requires that the index *already exists*. Use `list.append()` to add new indices, instead.

Comment: Just modified the two lines: data[i]['category'][j].append({'name':cateList[j]})
        data[i]['category'][j].append({'subcategory':defaultdict(list)}) and it works now. Thanks a lot Martijin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec states you wanted `'Category'` to reference a *list*:

```
data = {0:{'data':0, 'Category':[
#                               ^ a list opening bracket
```

but instead, your code makes it a dictionary:

```
data[i]['category'] = defaultdict(list)
```

but the remainder of your code then attempts to treat the `'category'` object as a list again, by using `j` as an index. Because it's a dictionary instead, the expression `data[i]['category'][j]` produces a list, and `data[i]['category'][j]['name']` or `data[i]['category'][j]['subcategory']` tries to index that list with a string.

Building this structure really doesn't require a `defaultdict`; you already know you want to *build* data, and you are building the nested structures right there with loops. You can just use regular dictionaries and lists:

```
cateList = ["Main Dish", "Drink"]
n = 3 # n means the number of datasets

data = {}
for i in range(n):
    data[i] = {
        'data': i,
        'category': []
    }
    category = data[i]['category']
    for name in cateList:
        category.append({
            'name': name,
            'subcategory': []
        })
```

I'm not quite sure why you are building an outer dictionary with integer keys starting at 0. You could just make that a list too.

Comment: Martijn, thanks a lot for this elegant solution. I was given the task to do this structure, and the first dataset starts as an dictionary...I guess I have to confirm with my teammate on this..much obliged!